# Enable compress for TortoiseGitPlink

Tags: ssh, compression, putty, tortoisegit

How can I enable compress option (*-C*) for TortoiseGitPlink?

I have tried add *-C* option in TortoiseGit Setting -> Network -> SSH Client. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly pass arguments to the SSH tool used by git.

TortoiseGitPlink as well as Plink rely on PuTTY sessions: Download and run PuTTY. There you can either modify the "Default settings" which will be used for all new connections or create a new session for a specific server/connected as described [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html#tgit-ssh-faq-defaultkey).

Comment: @d0as8 Hi, it's common on StackOverflow to accept or upvote an answer in order to say thank you (of course, onlys if it helped you).